# how can I insert value into a table in sql server 2000 , 2005, 2008?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have a table having a single auto Auto Incremented column. How Can i insert the value. Using

> Insert into table or some other way

Thanks
Waiting for your replay..

Answer (score 4, accepted):

http://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=90116

provided some insight here.

```
INSERT INTO TableName DEFAULT VALUES
```

Answer (score 1):

```
CREATE TABLE products
(
   Id int IDENTITY(1,1) PRIMARY KEY
)
GO    


SET IDENTITY INSERT ON

INSERT INTO MyTable (Id) VALUES (2)

SET IDENTITY INSERT OFF
```

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing your table schema it's not going to be possible to give you a *good* answer, but you could do something like:

```
insert into tableName (column2, column3, column4) values (value2, value3, value4)
```

Since you're using an autoincrement column you don't need to specify it when inserting data.

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO tableName (columnName1, ...) VALUES (value1, ...);
```

Answer (score 0):

you can either

```
insert into tableName ()
```

either "insert into tableName VALUES (NULL)" where NULL is the first and only column value of the row (the syntax is

```
insert into tableName(column2, column3) VALUES (value2, value3)
```

as provided by Michael.
)